# Write unit test for @View Child

Tags: angular

I have an Angular6 component, which dynamic load another Angular component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

import { CompItem } from '../../../core/pages/servicecatalog/models/comp.item.model';
import { CompComponent } from '../../../core/pages/servicecatalog/models/comp.compoent.model';
import { CompDirective } from '../../directive/comp-directive.directive';
import { CompService } from '../../services/comp.service';

import * as _ from 'lodash';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-component-holder',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-component-holder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-component-holder.component.css']
})
export class DynamicComponentHolderComponent implements OnInit {

  comp: CompItem;
  @ViewChild(CompDirective) compHost: CompDirective;

  customUiList: Array<CompItem> = [];

  componentRef: any;

  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialogRef<DynamicComponentHolderComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public receivedData: any,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _componentService: CompService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCustomComponentList();
  }

  loadComponent() {
    const dynamicItem = this.comp;

    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(dynamicItem.component);

    const viewContainerRef = this.compHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<CompComponent>this.componentRef.instance).data = this.receivedData.data;


    <CompComponent>this.componentRef.instance.
    updateEmitter.subscribe((response) => {
    this.dialog.close({ confirm: true, orderid: response.orderNumber, orderNumber: response.orderNumber });
    });

    // Default Close Emitter
    <CompComponent>this.componentRef.instance.
      closeEmitter.subscribe((response) => {
        this.closeDialog('close');
      });

  }

  getCustomComponentList() {
    this._componentService.getComponents()
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          if (response.length > 0) {
            response.forEach((comp) => {
              this.customUiList.push(comp);
            });
            const classNameIndex = _.findIndex(this.customUiList, (o) => {
              return o.data.displayName == this.receivedData.data.customComponent;
            });
            if (classNameIndex > -1) {
              this.comp = this.customUiList[classNameIndex];
              this.loadComponent();
            }
          }
        }
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  }

  closeDialog(param: any) {
    <CompComponent>this.componentRef.destroy();
    this.dialog.close({ confirm: false });
  }


}


<ng-template comp-host></ng-template>
```

I am trying to write UT for this, but i am getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
>       at DynamicComponentHolderComponent.subscribe [as loadComponent] (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/service-catalog/custom-ui-components/dynamic-component-holder/dynamic-component-holder.component.ts:40)

How can I do UT for dynamic Angular component.subscribe?

Please help.

SPECT.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DynamicComponentHolderComponent } from './dynamic-component-holder.component';
import { MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { CompService } from '../../services/comp.service';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, Component, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { CompItem } from '../../../core/pages/servicecatalog/models/comp.item.model';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { CompDirective } from '../../directive/comp-directive.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-settings',
  template: '<p>Mock Product Settings Component</p>'
})
class MockRefreshComponent {}


describe('DynamicComponentHolderComponent', () => {
  let component: DynamicComponentHolderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DynamicComponentHolderComponent>;

  const MatDialogRefMock = {
    close: jasmine.createSpy('close')
  };

  // tslint:disable-next-line:quotemark
  const passedData = {"data":{"categoryIds":[{"parentId":"5c3f08a7dc57c0002e3e8506","status":"Active","_id":"5c3f08b5dc57c0002e3e8507","name":"userCat-2","description":"userCat-2","createdAt":"2019-01-16T10:34:29.280Z","updatedAt":"2019-01-16T10:34:29.280Z","__v":0}],"tags":["refresh"],"status":"Active","orderFormKey":[],"headers":[],"userGroup":[{"id":"377c866e-7b43-4c5f-87fd-461c296412df","group":"service-catalog","description":"service catalog group","isAdmin":false,"created_at":"2018-12-27T04:56:57.493Z"}],"workflow":[],"_id":"5c4662df0042bc008aa1acb7","name":"Refresh Cisco Ip Phone","description":"Refresh Cisco Ip Phone","orderFormType":"customComponent","customComponent":"Refresh Cisco IP Phone","createdAt":"2019-01-22T00:25:03.626Z","updatedAt":"2019-01-22T00:25:03.626Z","__v":0,"favourite":true,"favouriteId":"5c46b56b11d3e50064cc41f5"}};

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        DynamicComponentHolderComponent,
        MockRefreshComponent,
        CompDirective
      ],
      imports: [
        MatDialogModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: passedData },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: MatDialogRefMock },
        { provide: CompService, useClass: MockComponentService}
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });

    TestBed.overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
      set: {
        entryComponents: [MockRefreshComponent]
      }
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DynamicComponentHolderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('will have the  `ViewChild`s defined', () => {
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.compHost).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('expect close Dialog to be called', () => {
    const closeDialog = spyOn(component, 'closeDialog').and.callThrough();
    component.closeDialog('close');
    expect(closeDialog).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});

class MockComponentService {
  getComponents() {
    return of([
      new CompItem(MockRefreshComponent, {
        'displayName': 'Refresh Cisco IP Phone',
        'name': 'refreshCiscoIpPhone',
        'componentName': 'refresh-cisco',
        'classname': 'RefreshCiscoComponent',
        'width': '90%',
        'height': '95vh',
        'maxWidth': '95vw',
        'maxHeight': '95vh',
      })
    ]);
  }
}

export function MockDirective(options: Component): Directive {
  const metadata: Directive = {
    selector: options.selector,
    inputs: options.inputs,
    outputs: options.outputs
  };
  return <any>Directive(metadata)(class _ {}); // <----- add <any>
}
```

Comment: Can you post your spec.ts file for the component ?

Comment: @RanikaNisal, it added

Comment: You're trying to access the view child from inside a subscribe callback in ngOnInit. If the observable returned by MockComponentService is synchronous, you're thus trying to acces the view child from ngOnInit. But the view child will only be available in ngAfterViewInit.